# Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f(\cdot+t) \to f$ pointwise as $t \to 0$

Tags: analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a function.

Prove that $f$ is uniformly continuous if and only if $f(•+t) \to f$ in $L_{∞}$ as $t\to0$

Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f(•+t) \to f$ pointwise as $t \to 0$

Comment: Instead of `->`, use `\to`. Also, what do $R$ and $C$ stand for?

Comment: How do you define continuous and uniformly continuous? The above are almost synonymous with the usual definitions...

Comment: Then the above are almost synonymous with the definitions. What are you having difficult with?

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the first:

> $f$ is uniformly continuous iff $f(x + t) \to f(x)$ in $L_\infty$ as $t \to 0$.

Firstly, what does it mean to have convergence in $L_\infty$? We say that $\displaystyle ||h(x) - g(x)||_\infty = \sup_{x} |h(x) - g(x)|$. So $f(x+t) \to f(x)$ in $L_\infty$ is the same as saying that $\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0} \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x+t) - f(x)| = 0$, which is an almost direct rephrasing of the definition of uniform continuity. So we see that $f$ is uniformly continuous iff $f(x+t) \to f(x)$ in $L_\infty$.

The same thing is true about the second one you ask about - it's almost a direct rephrasing of the definition of continuity.